# Propability for drawing a specific card in a card game.

Tags: probability

Assume a card game with a deck of 60 cards. The deck contains the same card 4 times. When the game starts you can draw seven cards. Now, what is the probability for halding one of the 4 cards in your initial draw of 7?

I figured that I have to use the hypergeometric distribution with the parameters:
$$
    N = 60 \\
    K = 4 \\
    n = 7  \\
    k = 1 \text{//since I'd like to have one of the 4 cards in my hand.}
$$

But this seems to be incorrect. A site describing the problem said, you have to use the inverse and assume you draw none of the 4 cards. Something like this:

$$
    N = 60 \\
    K = 4 \\
    n = 7 \\
    k = 0 
$$
And take the inverse 1-HYPERGEO. I cannot understand why this is the case?

Comment: Seems like overkill to me... the probability of you not taking it on the first turn is $\frac{56}{60}$... on the second turn is $\frac{55}{59}$ etc.

Comment: I see your point. But my question is, why cant I use hypergeo and set in 1 as success? Why do I have to work with the inverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You and the website are solving two different problems.  You are finding the probability of drawing exactly one of the four "good" cards.  The website is finding the probability of drawing at least one of the good cards.  But it's not the inverse, it's simply "one minus" the hypergeometric.  I.e., the probability of drawing at least one good card is one minus the probability of drawing no good cards:
$$p = 1- \frac{\binom{56}{7}}{\binom{60}{7}}$$
(I would call this the "complementary" problem, not the "inverse" problem, if that's what you mean.)